# Choosing between changing visibility or recreating a control

Tags: .net, wpf, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to design a wpf application with multiple interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127620/how-to-design-a-wpf-application-with-multiple-interfaces)

I'm building a newsletter application. First, when the program is launched, two main buttons are displayed - "Messages" and "Recipients". Whatever is clicked, another content is displayed.

My question is: should I hide/close the first window and create/make visible another window or just change the visibility of controls?

I have different thoughts, because for a small application like mine, it may seem that changing the visibility of the control would be enough. However, I actually don't know where is the border and whether the application is small enough. After clicking "Messages", a list of messages would be displayed with various options to manipulate them - browse, delete, edit, add, sort, filter etc.
The other button would do pretty much the same, but with recipients.

What is the regular approach? What would be good in my case?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3127620/590790

Comment: Consider a tab.  What do you mean by hide/close first window.  Either way I would just use one window then flop out the control or hide unhide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you think about performance or speed, as this is all pretty much instantaneous anyways.

I think the correct "approach" would be to have a generic control that can show a list of items (I'm thinking `ItemsControl`) and bind this to an observable list of custom model objects. These model objects would have the text in them and have methods like `browse`, `delete`, `edit` and such (I'm thinking `Command`s) that get's called from the GUI. When you show the one type of items, you would just put the ObservableList (that you've created somewhere in the background logic) into the DataContext so the `ItemsControl` can display it.

This is the normal MVVM approach that usually gets employed in WPF applications. If you want to keep it simple or you have no experience with MVVM (and don't want to gain some), I think it doesn't matter if you change the visibility or for example use a TabControl and put your views in different tabs.

Answer (score 1):

WPF unloads non-visible items, so changing the visibility to hide the item actually unloads the control, and showing it again will reload it. This means the performance difference between the two is pretty similar, as the only real difference is creating the object itself.

My usual preference is to use a single `ContentControl` that has it's `Content` bound to whatever the `ActiveWindow` object is, and swap the `ActiveWindow` to a different one when needed. This eliminates the need to mess with visibility or window management altogether, which makes my life easier.

But that's definitely no "rule". I usually do whatever works best for the application flow, and only worry about it if I notice a significant performance hit when loading/unloading the control (which occurs regardless of if I make a new item or toggle its visibility).

In those special cases, I use a [customized extended `TabControl`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12824709/302677) which stores the `ContentPresenter` of each item in memory, and reloads it from memory when it needs to be displayed again instead of re-creating it. This fixes the performance lag of redrawing the control, but it does make the application use more memory, so I only use it if I actually notice a performance problem when switching views.

Comment: _"WPF unloads non-visible items"_? Really? Then only when set to Collapsed I presume?

Comment: @StevenJeuris Nope, when you set them `Hidden` as well. Give it a test - add a `Loaded` and `Unloaded` event to an object and toggle its visibility. The events get run.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to decide based on which you prefer, speed or memory consumption.

- You'll get optimal **speed** when just changing visibility of the controls since you don't have to reconstruct them each them you show them.
- You'll get a **lower memory footprint** when you only keep those controls you are actually displaying in memory.

For such a small application as yours I wouldn't worry too much about it. Chances are when the controls are really small you can't even notice the difference in speed or memory anyhow.